# Find conditions like 'NOT EXISTS'

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have 2 tables in my db...

**Entita**
id *int(11)*
descrizione *varchar(50)*
.....

**Publicobjects**
....
model *varchar(50)* the model I need (in this case *'Entita'*)
model_id *int(11)*

I would like to make a query like this:
`select entita.*
from entita
where NOT EXISTS (select * from publicobjects where publicobjects.model = 'Entita' and publicobjects.model_id = entita.id)`

How can I do this with the model functions of Cakephp without use custom query?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is a valid (My)SQL expression, and I can't really imagine how you would select non-existing records anyway. Can you describe in words what you want to get?

Comment: Yes, is a valid MySql expression... see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html :)

Comment: Oops, learned something new. :) I've never used it and interestingly it didn't even come out when searching for it in the MySQL docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're trying to find rows from the Entita table that are not in the Publicobjects table.  Assuming that is correct, here is the SQL query for MySQL to find it:

```
SELECT `entita`.*
FROM `entita` 
LEFT JOIN `publicobjects` ON (`publicobjects`.`model` = 'entita' 
    AND `publicobjects`.`model_id` = `entita`.`id`)
WHERE `publicobjects`.`model_id` IS NULL
```

To make this work with CakePHP's models takes a couple of steps.  I've made some assumptions about your model names, but I could be wrong and those are easy to fix.

First add this to the Entita model:

```
<?php
var $hasOne = array('Publicobject' => array(
    'foreignKey' => 'model_id',
    'conditions' => 'Publicobject.model = "Entita"'));
```

Now, you can check for entries that are missing in the Publicobjects table like this:

```
<?php
$this->Entita->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Publicobject.model_id IS NULL')));
```

Comment: I forgot to consider LEFT JOIN on my query... I used NOT EXISTS that is the same... :) Thanks!

However, if I want to select only 'Entita' that are also on 'Publicobject' I've to change conditions: 'Publicobject.model_id IS NOT NULL'... :)